# Signed measure defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $ (X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $ f:X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ be an integrable function (i.e. at least one of $ f_+ $ and $ f_-$ is integrable).
I want to prove that $ \lambda:\mathcal{M}\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ defined as

$$ \lambda(E)=\int_{E}f d\mu $$

is a *signed measure*.

When I prove the countable additivity, how can I prove that the series $$ \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\int_{E_i}f d\mu$$ may only converge absolutely or diverge?

Comment: Can it not help if you define $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right):=\int f_{+}d\mu$,
$\lambda_{-}\left(E\right):=\int f_{-}d\mu$ and finally $\lambda\left(E\right):=\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)-\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)$?
Then $\lambda_{+}$and $\lambda_{-}$ are both measures and at least
one of them is finite.

Comment: Then how can I prove that these series cannot oscillate?

Comment: Are the sets $E_i$ disjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define for every $E\in\mathcal M$:

$\lambda_{+}\left(E\right):=\int_{E}f_{+}d\mu$, $\quad\lambda_{-}\left(E\right):=\int_{E}f_{-}d\mu$
and finally $\lambda\left(E\right):=\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)-\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)$.

Let $E=\cup_{i}E_{i}$ where the $E_{i}$ are measurable and disjoint.
Then $\sum_{i}\left|\lambda\left(E_{i}\right)\right|=\sum_{i}\left[\lambda_{+}\left(E_{i}\right)+\lambda_{-}\left(E_{i}\right)\right]=\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)+\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)$.
If $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)+\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)<\infty$ then
the sequence converges absolutely. If $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)+\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)=\infty$
then $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)=\infty\wedge\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)<\infty$
or $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)<\infty\wedge\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)=\infty$.
In both cases $\sum_{i}\lambda\left(E_{i}\right)$ diverges. In the
first case to $+\infty$ and in the second to $-\infty$. The option
$\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)=\infty=\lambda_{-}\left(E\right)$  is not
there since it contradicts that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: All clear except for the last passage. In which way the fact that $\ f $ is integrable does imply that the series cannot oscillate?

Comment: $f$ integrable means that at least one of $\int f_{+}d\mu$ and $\int f_{-}d\mu$ is finite.
Then $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)\leq\lambda_{+}\left(X\right)=\int f_{+}d\mu<\infty$
or $\lambda_{+}\left(E\right)\leq\lambda_{-}\left(X\right)=\int f_{-}d\mu<\infty$.

Comment: If it is still unclear then tell me what you mean exactly by oscillate.

Comment: Why $\ \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\int_{E_i}f_+ d\mu $ and $\ \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\int_{E_i}f_- d\mu $ have to exist?

Comment: Both are summations of *nonnegative* terms and both are allowed to diverge to $+\infty$. Such 'things' always exist. The only thing is that they cannot *both* diverge to $+\infty$ (that would contradict the integrability of $f$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: You are very welcome. I dropped the remark about 'oscillate' from my answer. I don't think that is relevant. the sign of the term in the summation is allowed to switch between $+$ and $-$ without doing any harm. It will not disturb divergence or absolute convergence.